Make one column weigh double as much as another column inside GridLayoutManager on the IntelliJ GUI designer
Is it possible to make it so that two columns which both have the "Want grow" property in the GridLayoutManager take up different proportions?
As in like, instead of them both taking equally as much space of what is left after all of the columns which are not "want grow" have been placed, make one take up double as much space as the other one, kind of like with the property "layout_columnWeight" in Android.
If there is no such thing, is there any work around or am I stuck with two columns that are always equal whenever resizing the frame?
(For reference, these 2 columns are next to each other and have more columns around them which do not have the "want grow" property)

Create a Nested Grid Layout: Use nested panels to simulate column weights., then Set "Want grow" Property: Apply the "Want grow" property to the nested panels and manage their proportions using the GridLayoutManager setting

You use a different "weightx" constraint for each column. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on How to Use GridBagLayout
